# Is the iSCSI initiator installed and running by default on Win 2008 R2 and Win 2012

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, iscsi

Basically, the title says it all.

I really appreciate your responses.

Comment: Did you even google this before asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its installed in both but will prompt you if you try and use it and it isn't enabled.
iSCSI target (the server) is not installed in 2008r2 but is available from MS and is a feature in 2012.